# Get processId and returnValue from ManagementObject.InvokeMethod Method

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm using WMI to execute a command remotely, as mentioned in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobject.invokemethod?view=netframework-4.8#System_Management_ManagementObject_InvokeMethod_System_String_System_Object___):

```
    //Execute the method
    object result = 
        processClass.InvokeMethod(
        "Create", methodArgs);

    //Display results
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Creation of process returned: " + result);
```

I need to retrieve the PID and return value from the `result` object (not as a string, but two separate value), but the document didn't mention it.

Does anyonw know?

Comment: instead of returning an `Object at the result, you can return `ManagementBaseObject`  which have `returnValue` and `processId`

Comment: @styx I have resolved this problem, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

ProcessId and returnValue can be obtained like this:

```
UInt32 retcode = 
    processClass.InvokeMethod(
    "Create", methodArgs);

UInt32 pid = methodArgs[3];
```